# My laptop doesn't detect my wi-fi

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, laptop

Recently my old dell laptop started to work very slowly, so I decided to install linux on it. I choosed debian (cause i like it). everything was ok, i installed drivers, programs etc. but when I tried to connect to my wi-fi (before i had used ethernet) it didn't detect it (but detected 30 routers of my neighbors). However when i tried to use my phone as hotspot it worked. How i can fix it?
Spec: router ASUS RT-N56U (it offer 5GHz but I use 2.4 istead [idk why, don't ask]) (SSID rubikon)
laptop DELL inspirion 1545

[ip link show](https://justpaste.it/5qc05)
[lspci](http://justpaste.it/50ghs)

Comment: Is it you network 5GHz?

Comment: Please edit your question to add some essential information: the make and model of your WiFi adapter/chip. First run `ip link show` or `ifconfig -a` to list all detected network adapters; typically the WiFi adapter is named either `wlan0` or `wlo1` but it might be different. Then run `ethtool -i <WiFi adapter name>` and edit the output into your question, please. The outputs of `lspci -nn` and/or `lsusb` (whichever is appropriate) would be useful too. Some Broadcom WiFi chips have a very limited list of channels supported when the reverse-engineered `b43` driver is used.